# $b^n$ is irrational, where $b>1$ is a integer and $n$ is an irrational

Tags: number-theory

How to prove that the power $b^n$ is an irrational number, where $b$ is an integer greater than $1$ and $n$ is an irrational number?

Comment: This is not true. A counterexample is $b = 2$, $n = \log_2 3$, $b^n = 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) shows that if you assume that $n$ is algebraic, then $b^n$ is indeed irrational, in fact transcendental! You can even take $b$ to be algebraic.

So we can ask whether there's an easy proof that $ b^n $ is irrational for *b* integral and *n* an *algebraic* irrational.